# How can I make ring BLE device with cordova-plugin-ble-central plugin?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova-plugin-ble-central plugin on my project. I tried to make a sound on iBeacon by setting value in Immediate Alert Service. The value was written but the device doesn't ring. How can I make the iBeacon to ring and make the sound?
I am using [Minew-Blooetooth Tracker F4](http://www.minewtech.com/minew-web-en/minew_f4.html) ble device.
Code:
  `cordovaPluginBleCentral.writeWithoutResponse(
    'Some device id',
    '1802',
    '2A06',
    new Uint8Array([0x02]).buffer,
    successCallback,
    failureCallback
)`
I wrote that code regarding to GATT specification for [Immediate Alert Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.immediate_alert.xml).

Comment: What sort of beacon is it?  Standard iBeacons do not act as peripherals and cannot make a sound. You need to edit your question to show any relevant code and include any links to documentation on your hardware.

Comment: @Paulw11 I edited my question. Thanks for the suggestion.